# Proving $X\sim Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$, a bijection. Suppose $X\subseteq A$ and $Y\subseteq B$ are two sets such that $f(X)\subseteq Y$ and $f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq X$. Show that $X\sim Y$ and $f/X$ is the bijection between them.

Can you help me show it directly without the use of cardinals? On the one hand, it's kinda intuitive claim, but on the other hand I'm having difficulty writting it down.

Thanks.

Comment: What is an equivalence function? A bijection?

Comment: Indeed. I will change it to make it clear

Comment: $f$ restricted to $X$ is both surjective (on $Y$) and injective. Check those two separately, and you're more or less done.

Comment: First note that; $f\circ f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq Y$ and $f^{-1}\circ f(Y)\supseteq Y$; Then 

$f(X)\subseteq Y\Rightarrow f^{-1}\circ f(X)\subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$

Since $f^{-1}\circ f(X)\supseteq X$

We have; $X\subseteq f^{-1}\circ f(X)\subseteq f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq X$.

So; $f(X)=Y$

Comment: @OBDA, do you think the use of composition is essential here?

Comment: @Elimination Yes, I think. It remains to show that the restriction is also a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the restriction of an injective function to a subset of the domain is still an injective function. Also the inverse of a bijection is still a bijection. Also, Cantor-Berstein.

Comment: I'd rather not to use Cantor-Berstein. Is your hint implying using composition, as @OBDA did?

Comment: Cantor-Bernstein is a pretty fundamental theorem in set theory and it's generally used to make life easier for yourself. You could directly prove that $f|_X$ is a bijection onto $Y$ by using the result that a restriction of an injective function is injective, and then prove by contradiction that it must be surjective on $Y$ (because otherwise $f^{-1}|_Y$ would not have its image contained in $X$).

Comment: Understood, Thanks. I know Cantor-Bernstein is widely used though this exercise is an educational one :)